# How to enable a button once all form fields pass

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, typescript

My first Angular 5 app.

I've read through: https://angular.io/guide/form-validation and several pages I googled to find the answer, only to find that they're all really out of date.

I have multiple input boxes on my form like:

```
<form name="pizzaPlaceForm" class="form-container">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Shop Name" [(ngModel)]="pizzaPlace.shopName"
           id="shopName" name="shopName" #shopName="ngModel"
           required minlength="4">
    <mat-error>You must provide a shop name at least 4 characters in length.</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <br/>
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Contact Name" [(ngModel)]="pizzaPlace.contactName"
           id="contactName" name="contactName" #contactName="ngModel"
           required minlength="4">
    <mat-error>You must provide a contact name at least 4 characters in length.</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Now I want to control the disabled state of my button and only enable it when all of the required fields have been entered, like:

```
<button mat-raised-button disabled="pizzaPlaceForm.$invalid" (click)="onCreateClick()" *ngIf="createMode">Create</button>
```

Only it doesn't appear that $invalid works any more, so how do I do this with Angular 5?

Comment: The dollar sign for services is an `angularjs` conceit. In ``angular` it's just `invalid`.

Answer (score 2):

you want to disable the button if the form is not valid. so you can try below

```js
<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!pizzaPlaceForm.valid" (click)="onCreateClick()" *ngIf="createMode">Create</button>
```

Comment: You can simply use `pizzaPlaceForm.invalid` instead `!pizzaPlaceForm.valid`

Answer (score 0):

Add an identifier for the form with an `ngForm`.  Then you can disabled the submit button
with [disabled] attribute.

`[disabled]="pizzaPlace.form.invalid"` OR `[disabled]="pizzaPlace.invalid"`

```
<form  #pizzaPlace="ngForm"  name="pizzaPlaceForm" class="form-container">



<button mat-raised-button [disabled]="pizzaPlace.form.invalid" (click)="onCreateClick()" *ngIf="createMode">Create</button>

</form>
```